# Blender 2.91 vertex groups not working

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

I just downloaded 2.91. I know how to add vertex groups, I was just long for code for scripting, but this isn't functioning anymore.
I went to add a vertex group, but can't select the group to assign it. The font is orange and acts as if grayed out. Has anyone else noticed this?

Also the arrows for moving modifiers up and down are gone.

[image]

Comment: All seems to work here about vertex group. Concerning modifier arraw just drag and drop them using the upper right corner (this is so since 2.8)

Comment: I uninstalled 2.91, reinstalled 2.83 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: The orange looks like it’s your theme setting for selected. Reset to the default theme, and it should be more clear. You need to be in edit mode to assign to the vertex group.